# Get number of files within Android directory using adb shell

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, shell, subprocess

I am currently trying to use the following python code to get the number of files within a directory.

```
    output = subprocess.check_output(["adb", "shell", "cd /sdcard/Dir/Subdir", "find . -type f | wc -l"])
    print output
```

However, I am getting the output:

```
/system/bin/sh: cd: too many arguments

0
```

But If I enter the following in command prompt, I get the desired result (14 files):

```
adb shell
cd /sdcard/Dir/Subdir
find . -type f | wc -l
```

Any idea how to integrate the command line code into python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you pass arguments to `check_output` in a list (not in a string), then if you pass arguments with spaces they will be quoted.

But that's not the main problem here.

You're running `adb shell` in `check_output`, but next commands should be passed through proper command line or standard input of your shell.

You could try the following (untested):

```
output = subprocess.check_output(["adb", "shell", "cd /sdcard/Dir/Subdir", "&&","find . -type f | wc -l"])
```

(`&&` tells the shell to chain `cd` with `find` instead of passing all arguments to `cd`)

or run your shell interactively, and pass the commands like if you typed them (use `Popen` for that):

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["adb", "shell"],stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
out,err = p.communicate("cd /sdcard/Dir/Subdir\nfind . -type f | wc -l\n")
```